# Finding the operating point of this transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, bjt

Suppose we have the following transistor circuit:

[image]

We want to find the operating point (the collector current and the collector-emitter voltage).

In order to do this, we do a large signal analysis, meaning that our capacitors become open-circuited. Let's say the transistor has a base-emitter voltage of \$U_{BE}\$ and a current gain of \$\beta\$.

We can transform our circuit to:

[image]

We can now form three equations:

\$ E-R_CI_C-U_{CE}-(R_{E1}+R_{E2})(I_B+I_C) = -E\$

and...

\$ -R_BI_B-U_{BE}-(R_{E1}+R_{E2})(I_B+I_C) = -E\$

followed lastly by:

\$I_C=\beta I_B\$

Usually the node at the bottom of the image with voltage \$-E\$ has always been grounded in the problems I've done before. In this case, it isn't, so that makes me confused on whether I've derived the correct equations. I'd be glad for any feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: Those look correct. One note, we generally use V for voltage, your use of U might be confusing to some people.

Comment: If you want to do a very accurate analysis then yout equations look OK. But in practical calculations Ib is ignored and the base considered to be at 0V. This puts the emitter at -Vbe = - 0.7V and you can calculate Ie (=Ic) from ie= (E-0.7)/(Re1+Re2) and Vce is easy from there. To use any more accurate equations assumes you know the component values to a high degree of accuracy along with the transistor's parameters such as beta. The latter is usually specified on data sheets to no better than a factor of 2,  for example the 2N2222 min 100, nominal 200, max 300.

Comment: Tanamas, looks about right to me, as well. If \$ \left(\beta_{_\text{MIN}}+1\right)\cdot\left(R_{_{\text{E}_1}}+R_{_{\text{E}_2}}\right) \gg R_{_{\text{B}}}\$ (the emitter resistance reflected back to the base and compared with the base resistance) you may also ignore the base current as @Peter suggests and simplify still more. Otherwise, to remain sufficiently accurate you probably need to consider the base current.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who commented. I’ll make sure to take your points into consideration when solving problems.